# MySQL Select Joins with Unique columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

I have a table called retail sellers. Its fields are

```
retail location ID, 
retail location name, 
address, 
phone number.
```

I have another table called projects with the fields

```
project id,
project name, 
state id, 
target release date.
```

I have another table called inventory with the fields

```
retail location id, 
project id, 
inventory number, 
amount.
```

I want to do a select with probably left joins i think(very very new to sql) that obtains the project names for projects that are only available at a specific retail location, the henry downtown location.

I have more than one location in my retail locations table and all of my retail locations are referenced in the inventory table by their retail location ID. I can get all of the project names sold at the `henry downtown` location but am unsure how to just get the ones that are only sold there and not at other retail locations. Pls help currently I have

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Project`.`Name`
FROM `Retail Sellers`
 LEFT JOIN `testDatabase`.`Inventory` ON `Retail Sellers`.`Retail Location ID` = `Inventory`.`Retail Location ID` 
 LEFT JOIN `testDatabase`.`Project` ON `Inventory`.`Project ID` = `Project`.`Project ID` 
WHERE (`Retail Sellers`.`Retail Location Name`='Henry Downtown')
ORDER BY `Project`.`Name` ASC
```

I am not sure distinct is actually doing anything for me though. It currently returns 4 rows when there should only be two. Thanks for the help, any and all help is appreciated. I am using PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want the names, then you don't need left joins.

The answer to your question, though, is to use `group by` and `having`.  If you are learning SQL, there really is no reason to learn `select distinct`.  Almost everything it can do, `group by` can do better.

So:

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM `Retail Sellers` rs JOIN
     `testDatabase`.`Inventory` i
     ON rs.`Retail Location ID` = i.`Retail Location ID` JOIN 
     `testDatabase`.`Project` p
     ON i.`Project ID` = p.`Project ID` WHERE rs.`Retail Location Name` = 'Henry Downtown'
GROUP BY p.Name
HAVING MIN(p.`Retail Location Name`) = MAX(p.`Retail Location Name`) AND  -- there is only one name
       MIN(p.`Retail Location Name`) = 'Henry Downtown'
ORDER BY `Project`.`Name` ASC
```